# Atheros drivers support for wifi direct

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, atheros, wifi-direct

My laptop has a wireless pci (Atheros AR242x / AR252x) that doesn't seem to support 802.11n. By default it uses the ath5k kernel drivers.From 'iw list' command I can see that it doesn't support P2P-GO/CLIENT interfaces.I know that ath9k drivers support P2P-GO/CLIENT interfaces, but ath9k is compatible with 802.11n devices only.

My question is: Do I require a 802.11n supported wireless card in order to use Wifi-Direct? If it is no,then how do I get my wireless card(Atheros AR242x / AR252x) to support wifi-direct? or Is there a way where I can make it use ath9k(which support wifi-direct) instead of ath5k?

I use ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 802.11n support is mandatory for Wifi direct.And even if you make your wireless pci use ath9k, you still can't use wifi direct.See under supported chipsets in the link http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k